# How to get Total of price from json

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

**Solution**

To get total price from loop in json we need to use `$tot += +$data['price'].",";` in below code

```
$arr = '[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 11,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 15,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 10,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}]';

//print_r($arr);

$arr = json_decode($arr,TRUE);

foreach ($arr as $data)
{
  $tot += +$data['price'].",";
}

echo "Total = ".rtrim($tot,',');
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: I have given an answer for this question and Question is: How to get Total of price from json

Comment: You need to go and take a look at how to use the site. This is not how to answer your own question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I want alternate answer for this quesion. I got one answer and i am waiting for another answer from users.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
$arr = json_decode($arr,TRUE);
echo "Total = ".array_sum(array_column($arr,"price"));
```

[array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) - Calculate the sum of values in an array

[array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) - Return the values from a single column in the input array

Give it a try, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

$arr = json_decode($arr,TRUE);

```
foreach ($arr as $data)
{
  $tot[] =$data['price'];
}

echo "Total=".array_sum($tot);
```